# Is there a proper word that conveys the same meaning as “stealthed”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a word to replace the word “stealthed” in my manuscript. I’ve been using it as an verb/adjective to mean “to enter stealth mode” or “currently in stealth mode” as the characters I’m writing about are wearing glow-in-the-dark robotic suits that have a stealth feature that deactivates their glow and sound effects.

Example:

> When we’re stealthed, we don’t make any noise, so it’s not like people can hear us coming.

I’ve even used the phrase “un-stealth” as a word at one point because I don’t know of a proper verb to convey the meaning I’m looking for.

Example:

> Scout, un-stealth, then bring in the driver.

“Disguise” comes close; however, the characters are already disguised by their suits. (The gimmick is that they’re disguising themselves as people wearing robotic suits when they’re actually superhuman.) I need a verb or verbal phrase that specifically means “to become stealthier or less conspicuous.” Although I could say “deactivate stealth mode,” “activate stealth mode,” “when we are in stealth mode,” at every occurrence. I’m concerned it will get redundant and would love a shorter way to express this.

Comment: "in stealth mode" is pretty neologistic, but it has a range of meanings, so you can't necessarily expect any existing single-word verbs to cover all of them. Sometimes, ***camouflaged*** or ***cloaked*** will work, but not always.

Comment: Most online definitions say things like ***Stealth mode** is a way of operating a startup in which the goal is to maintain secrecy and to avoid letting other people know what it is that you're working on*. But I suspect that's not *exactly* what you mean.

Comment: _Hidden_ is another adjective formed from the passive participle of a verb, in this case _hide_. Using _stealth_ as a verb is a new usage, but it exists -- _They are now stealthing their mid-range bombers_. However, _hide_ is a much more common word, and so is _hidden_. Both refer to making it difficult to see something.

Comment: @JohnLawler That is not (in my experience) the most common meaning of "stealth" as a verb; [see Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stealthing). The title of the question puzzled me.

Comment: Once you use a special word in a coded way, your reader gets it—no apologies needed.

Comment: In our dimension, we don't currently have "glow-in-the-dark robotic suits that have a stealth feature", so we don't have any popular words to describe how they're used.  *Stealthed* is an understandable and reasonable word for this in your madeup world.  Is there a reason why you want to replace it?

Comment: @Juhasz  I would recommend against it, because the slang usage I listed above is so widely known as to be distracting.

Comment: Personally, I find verbing stealth pretty awful.

Comment: There's a good argument for using a neologism (or existing word in a new sense) for a new thing, but the OP doesn't seem to want that, if "proper word" means existing word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Cloak is exactly the word I was looking for and perfectly fits this context.

Comment: @StuartF Your point is exactly right. Since I knew that there was a word for this, I didn’t want to keep using “stealth” incorrectly. I didn’t want to use a neologism when it wasn’t necessary because I’ve already done so in other parts of the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some words spring to mind:

- hidden
- concealed
- cloaked (often used in science fiction in a very similar way)
- unlighted
- lightless
- dark/darkened ("go dark" is often used when e.g. ships turn off their transponders)
- obscure/obscured
- camouflaged
- undetectable
- disappeared (e.g. to disappear from radar, though the past participle is uncommon)
- vanished

You could also invent your own informal slang for fun, e.g.: "she was probably gone at that moment; when we're gone, they can't detect us".

Comment: Cloak is exactly the word I wanted. I was pretty sure it existed, but I couldn’t call it to mind. This is a science-fiction work. I realize now I should’ve clarified that in the question because vocabulary is sometimes applied differently in science-fiction. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RELavender: Ah, that sounds like a good fit, then. Good luck on your writing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **concealed**.

> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concealed)
> kept hidden or where it cannot easily be seen

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concealed)
> kept out of sight or hidden from view

So you could say

> When we’re concealed, we don’t make any noise, so it’s not like people can hear us coming.

Comment: Also synonyms such as **covert**, **obscured** and **screened**.